# Corebluetooth: How can I get the human readable name of a central while working as a peripheral manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am writing a program to share data with other devices via BLE. I was wondering if there is any way to retrieve the human-readable name of other connected devices, like "My iPad" or "Nexus 9"? I've checked the CBPeripheralManager and CBPeripheralManagerDelegate Class references and found nothing useful.